# rdp session not showing "open terminal" or other options

Tags: 18.04, xrdp, hyper-v

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 on hyper-v on windows 10.0.17134.  The mouse is slow and I can't copy/paste to it, and apparently that's impossible without using term serv, so I installed xrdp on ubuntu with the following:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```

Then I ran mstsc and connected to the vm after logging out of hyper v (apparently you can't be logged in to both? I don't understand that either).  The connection worked, but I got an error saying "authentication required to create a color managed device" so I found this article https://github.com/TurboVNC/turbovnc/issues/47, put that block into the 3 different files listed there, and that error went away.

Now I can log in to termserv, but when I right click on the desktop I don't see "open terminal" or any of the other options that are supposed to be there.  It only has "change background", "display settings", and "settings".  There are also no app icons on the desktop and when I go into the app launcher, there are only 3 apps - everything else is missing.  I can't even open a terminal in there.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the polkit settings, ubuntu docs lists it here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp

Comment: Didn't work for me.